# Weird UIAccessibility Crash On Ipad Mini 2

Tags: uiaccessibility

Our app used Crashlytics to track app crash. One really weird crash was logged in Crashlytics. It only happened when using ipad mini. I never experienced the issue when testing on iphone 6s and iphone 6s plus.

`UIAccessibility _copyMultipleAttributeValuesCallback`

The following is crashlytic log screenshot.

[image: Crashlytics log]]

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I've just experienced exactly the same crash, on an iPad running iOS 10. No idea what caused it.

Answer (score 2):

Anything prefixed with `AX` or `_AX` is most likely a private accessibility class as well as `AXRuntime` is mose likely an internal framework. This means, unfortunately, that there is probably nothing you can do to fix this crash yourself.

However, filing a bug to Apple might help them resolve the issue. You can file bugs to Apple [here](http://bugreport.apple.com) and there is a dedicated Accessibility component that you can assign it to. Remember to include the stack trace and any other relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to file a bug report with Apple. I just experienced the same crash, so I've filed a bug report, and hope they will be able to solve this.